# How to set ANT_PATH in Jenkins from outside of the workspace?

Tags: ant, mercurial, jenkins

My file structure contains src/ folder with the project's source code, and this folder is the one I want to have in the jenkins' workspace.

However, I also have build folder which is needed for apache ant, and it is changing with every single "ant" command executed. The problem is this folder weights over 200mb. I don't want to end up pushing it to the repo everytime I run the "ant" command.

If someone who reads it has some experience with this - what's the best way to do it? Is it possible to pull src/ folder from the repo, and build/ folder from the system? But I guess it will be wrong because this way only I will be able to execute ant command...

What's the best way to set this?

Comment: Please make this question more explanative. I am not able to make out what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh?  You put `build` in your `.hgignore` file and then you'll not commit that directory or what's in it.  That's the usual setup, but maybe I'm missing some nuance of your question.